# strip the string in MySQL based on specific characters around

Tags: mysql, string, strip

I have a column with values that I need to strip. All the strings have the same pattern like the following:

```
Name
IIT | Cosmo (949446)
MIIT | World (949446)
HNTY | Name (576376)
```

I only need to grab the value that is in the middle. I was able to get this far:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Name`, '|', -1) as `New_Name`
```

Which gives me back `Cosmo (949446)`, `World (949446)`, `Name (576376)`
The desired output is: `Cosmo`, `World`, `Name`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substring_index on your output one more time.

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX("IIT | Cosmo (949446)", '|', -1),'(',1))
```

Comment: Works, thanks so much! I have accepted and upvoted the answer.